# spark-shell works with appropriate yarn resource settings but not spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

spark-shell on yarn(client mode) uses the yarn configurations specified in the $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf (creates 5 executors)

```
spark.master                            yarn
spark.driver.memory                     3g
spark.executor.cores                    1
spark.executor.memory                   3g
spark.executor.instances                5
```

but spark-submit on yarn (client mode) does not (spark-submit simply creates to 2 executors)

Comment: Hello @Akinwale did that worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your submitted job doesn't know which configuration to use thus try to set it explicitly, for example:

```
spark-submit --class "main.scala.Main" \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-memory 4g \
    --executor-memory 2g \
    --num-executors 6 \
    --executor-cores 2 \
    --queue default \
    sparkcompanymerge.jar
```

Or use --conf flag as specified in [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)